# gud-break doesn't work with jdb

Tags: spacemacs, java, gud

I successfully attach to my java app with emacs & gud, but `gud-break` doesn't work as expected: it runs only:

```
stop at :48
```

if the line number is 48. So even the class name is missing and the command fails. If I manually type in the gud prompt `stop at <class>:48` that also doesn't work, I must type in the full package name: `stop at com.app.Class:48`.

How can I make `gud` run the correct command? I found about `gud-def` but I am baffled that this is not done properly out of the box and secondly, `gud-def` allows to insert the file name (class name) but I have no idea how I would insert the package name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I got it... I started `jdb` with:

```
jdb -attach <port>
```

but starting it with:

```
jdb -attach <port> -sourcepath<source path on disk>
```

`gud-break` now works as expected.